# How to disable copy and cut in TextBox?

Tags: asp.net, html

In my webpage I want to disable copy and cut option in context menu on textbox.

Comment: Means you do not want to allow user right click or you want to handle Cntrl+C some what

Comment: At the end of the day if someone wants to do it bad enough they will find a way.  There is no way to ensure that data can not be copied from a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add a javascrip function to show a alert

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function nocopy()
    {
                alert("Copying is not allowed!");
                return false;
    }
   </script>
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" oncopy="return nocopy()">  </asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" oncopy="return false">  </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Which browsers support the oncopy event?

Comment: @DaveB I have tested it on IE8 and Firefox

Comment: And also in Chrome. thanx.

Answer (score 9):

This is my first post and I hope it will help.
Try this one:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="someId" runat="server" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" ondelete="return false"></asp:TextBox>
```

It will work for copy, paste, cut, and delete on most of the input controls.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for a non asp way but I just found out about on cut method in JavaScript. Do the following for your input:

```
<input oncopy='prevent()>

<script>
function prevent()
{
 event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

Works for me. Tested on chrome. Also disables copying from the context menu. Additionally this works for oncut and onpaste methods. Still trying to find a way for ondelete though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrevent" runat="server"  oncopy="return false"
         oncut="return false">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

for more see this [link](http://btewary.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-disable-copy-paste-and-cut-on.html)